# How to Disable a button in Yii2

Tags: php, button, yii2

I'm trying to disable the **Create Project** `Button` when the user is not logged in, the button will `Hide` or `disable`.

And this is my condition:

```
<p>
    <?php
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs']);
    } elseif(Yii::$app->user->identity->username) {
        Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
    }
    ?>
</p>
```

**It's working, But, when the user is logged in, the button is already Hide!**

How can disable or hide the button in Yii2 and fix that problem?

is there any tutorial about that?

Comment: Do you login with Ajax? Why it is hidden when user logs in?

Comment: On which condition does the last else part be processed? I don't know any other state either the user is a guest or logged in.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: 'disabled' attribute doesn't apply to <a> element. It might work in some browsers but you must not use it! If you want your link appear as disabled button, you should use plain text, (not Html::a) with appropriate styles. Another option is using a form element (Html::button or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just checking for `logged` in user then Use `!Yii::$app->user->isGuest` and you forget `echo`:

```
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        echo Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'])
}
```

Comment: now it's working, but with another button object(different button)btw tnx about that echo.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a `disabled` attribute to disable the button, or to hide it completely you can use CSS `style=display: none;`

Both are used in the code below

```
<p>
    <?php
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            // This button will be displayed, but is disabled 
            Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'disabled' => 'disabled']);
        } elseif(Yii::$app->user->identity->username) {
            Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
        } else {
            // This button will not be displayed (it is hidden)
            Html::a('Create a Project', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'style' => 'display: none;']);
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you cannot disable `a` tag. `disabled` attribute works fine on `Button` tags eg:

`<?= Html::Button('Project', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'disabled' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ]) ?>`

If you really want to disable `a` tag then you can use this example:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="a1" href="http://www.google.com">Google 1</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#a1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'disabled' class:

```
echo Html::a('Create Item', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn disabled']);
```

Found this approach accidentally while trying out a few solutions. :D