# Hidden Button in yii2

Tags: button, yii2

I want to disable the Download Button when the guest is not submit as guest, the button will hide or disable. And I'm using modal to submit Guest Form. I try to follow this [How to Disable a button in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254870/how-to-disable-a-button-in-yii2) , but I'm confused to declaration in statements. This is my button screenshoot >> 
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3JYh.jpg)

My script,

```
<p>     
<?php
if (Yii::$app->$model->'id_guest') {
  echo Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=>$model->file_buku],['class'=>'btn btn-primary'] ); 
} elseif(Yii::$app->$model->identity->'id_guest') {
   echo  Html::button('Create Guest', ['value'=>Url::to('index.php?r=guest/create'),'class' => 'btn btn-success','id'=>'modalButton']) ;
}
?></p>
```

I'm using gii to create Form Guest. Can you help me? 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest()) {
    echo Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=>$model->file_buku],['class'=>'btn btn-primary'] ); 
}
```

Here is the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)

Comment: I try to use u'r code, but I'm getting an error, Getting unknown property: ommon\models\User::nama. I read in documentation, that user is a class. But, I create another class, that is guest. So, I modifications my code being this if (Yii::$app->guest->getIsGuest()) {, but I got an error again. Can u help me?

Comment: in you view do you have this? use yii\web\User;